# Something went wrong while interacting with SharePoint in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have integrated CRM Online with SharePoint on-premise using Server-based integration. When I go to "Documents" area of a record, I get this error:

[image]

According to this post: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn946906.aspx, it says that "This error can be returned to the user who doesn’t have site permissions or the user has had permissions removed from the SharePoint site where Microsoft Dynamics CRM document management is enabled". But my user has Sys Admin role in CRM and can access the SharePoint site normally.

Please advise!

UPDATE: Turns out it is because of the load balancer. It always root requests too one server and the busy traffic causes CRM cannot connect to SharePoint in time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you check https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/enable-sharepoint-document-management-for-specific-entities.aspx ?
2. Check the security settings for the role. (As you mentioned, your SysAdmin should have all priviliges.)
3. Check the security settings on sharepoint. I had the same issue a couple of months ago. My CRM-Account has also a SysAdmin-role, but my Sharepoint-account did not have the required priviliges.
4. If you are running 2 systems (prod and test), you should check the settings the above mentioned settings on both systems. (The obvious things are mostly the common source for mistakes / errors.)
5. **This could be your problem's solution:** If you use WAD (Windows Active Directory) to authenticate users in CRM then check that your browser redirects the login information from browser => CRM => Sharepoint. We had an issue with Firefox concerning this. (There is some setting in Firefox' config, where you can explicitly forward your WAD-credentials to a specific site like sharepoint.)

EDIT:
5. This is the Firefox-setting: network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris

You can also checkout https://superuser.com/questions/594049/how-to-enable-ntlm-for-all-intranet-sites-in-firefox for further information.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Turns out it is an intermittent issue on SharePoint server. I am still working with SharePoint team about it.

Answer (score -1):

I recently experience this "Something Went Wrong" issue while uploading a file into Sharepoint from a CRM record.  Opening the Sharepoint Document location from CRM and attempting to upload the document directly into Sharepoint gave me a different,
[more specific error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH7vz.jpg)

Turns out it was just an issue with the file name containing special characters.